# navigation bar won't center

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to create a centered navigation bar with a 10px border top, left and right. but when i change the width it's stuck to the left of the page. if i put a margin they don't look evenly spaced. very new to this.

here's my current css

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>my name</title>
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap');
    
    body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #abecd6 0%, #fbed96 100%);
        box-sizing:border-box;
    nav {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #381D2A;
      justify-content: center;
      position: fixed;
      width: 99%;
      z-index: 1;
      border-radius: 20px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    }

    nav ul {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about-me">about me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact me">contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[image: how it looks]

[how i want it to look, but no matter the width of the browser window, as it only looks like this if it's stretched a certain amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWDH7.png)

Comment: Use `Padding` and `Margin`

Comment: Can you please add html and more css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use "**position: fixed;**", then you need to position it with "left/right" in order to make it center not **margin left/right**.

Edit:
Following your code example, I would do something like this

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #381D2A;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You need to understand [positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and how it works.

What I did in my code snippet:

1. instead of using margins, Im using **top, left, right** property to position the **nav** element
2. adjusting the width of the **nav** element using **calc(100% - 20px)** - why minus 20px? because we position our element 10px from the left edge and 10px from the right edge and we need to count that.

Comment: i am already using position:fixed, how would i use left/right to change the margin?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear.
Basically, if you using position "fixed or absolute" you are not positioning your element with margins, you should use position property like "left/right/top/bottom".

Hope that my updated answer have more sense now

Answer (score 1):

Make the width of the `nav` element take `100%` that way it is evenly distributed, and just add increase/decrease the `margin` as you see fit.

```
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #381D2A;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Also, make sure you have `box-sizing` set to `border-box` to tell the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing))

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Comment: i tried this but now i can't see the end of the element on the right (the border-radius is cut off, just goes off the page no matter how i try to adjust the margin). what could i be doing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I now saw that you using `postion: fixed`. Then the element is removed from the normal document flow, and is postioned with top, right, bottom and left property. So to get your desired layout you have to add:

```
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #381D2A;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  rigth: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

The calc in width property is calculating the width (in your case 100%) minus the value in left and right property, so you get your desired "margins".

I think you need to add `box-sizing: border-box` to body element:

```
body, * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The box-sizing property is adjusting the width/height when you add margin/padding. More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: added this but now my nav bar goes off the page (can't see the end of it, no matter how i adjust the margins. any advice? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #381D2A;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 99%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: this gave me problems similar to what i was facing where the end of the element looks different depending on how the browser is stretched.